# how to create worksheets from a dynamic lis of values in vb

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of values in a excel name range .I want to write a VB code so as to create worksheets using those list of values.These list of values keep on changing.

Here is the code:

```
Sub AddSheets()
Dim cell As Excel.Range
Dim wsWithSheetNames As Excel.Worksheet
Dim wbToAddSheetsTo As Excel.Workbook
Dim i As Integer
i = 0
Set wsWithSheetNames = ActiveSheet
Set wbToAddSheetsTo = ActiveWorkbook
For Each cell In wsWithSheetNames.Range("sheet_name").End(xlDown)
    With wbToAddSheetsTo
        .Sheets.Add after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
        On Error Resume Next
        ActiveSheet.Name = cell.Value
        If Err.Number = 1004 Then
          Debug.Print cell.Value & " already used as a sheet name"
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
Next cell
```

Here `sheet_name`(cells in a single column) is the namerange where the name of the sheets to be created is dumped.
The no of sheets may change.

My above code does not work correctly , it just creates the a sheet with the sheet name of last value in this range.Where am i going wrong? I am new to VB.what may be a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This line:

`For Each cell In wsWithSheetNames.Range("sheet_name").End(xlDown)`

Get rid of the `.End(xlDown)`, this is only grabbing the last value, as you said.

In naming the range, just using the name already has the entire range defined.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. Notice the line below in your script, and just get rid of .End(xldown) at the end.

---For Each cell In wsWithSheetNames.Range("sheet_name").End(xlDown)-----

change to

---For Each cell In wsWithSheetNames.Range("sheet_name")-----

Then it will add the individual sheetname one after another.